# how to retrieve Keys and values from json angular

Tags: angular

My json is as below.I need to retrieve key as 'test' from

```
((vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.name":"test") and value as testvalue from (vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.value":"testvalue")

    "vcap":{"vcap.services.site.volume_mounts":"",
             "vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.name":"test",
             "vcap.services.mq.credentials.credential_5.name":"A",
             "vcap.services.mq.credentials.credential_5.value":"Avalue",
             "vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.value":"testvalue"
           }
```

Sample code is really appreciable.

Comment: _Sample code is really appreciable._ yes that will be. Can you put your code?

Comment: You can access `key` by using `<your_object>['vcap']['vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.name']`, etc., assuming `vcap` is an attribute of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below code.

```js
var obj = {
 "vcap": {
  "vcap.services.site.volume_mounts": "",
  "vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.name": "test",
  "vcap.services.mq.credentials.credential_5.name": "A",
  "vcap.services.mq.credentials.credential_5.value": "Avalue",
  "vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.value": "testvalue"
 }
};

console.log('Key: ', obj['vcap']['vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.name']);

console.log('Value: ', obj['vcap']['vcap.services.kafka.credentials.credential_8.value']);
```